# fourier analysis book with measure theory as prerequisities

Tags: fourier-analysis, book-recommendation

Can someone lists out the good books on fourier analysis, but fourier analysis treatment should have prerequsities of measure theory, some Lp space, density knowledge etc. but at the same time easier to follow and is not serious. You can call it as first rigorous book on fourier analysis that uses things i mention above.

Comment: You could try "Numerical Fourier Analysis" by Tasche, Potts, Steidl and Plonka.

Comment: thank you.any more suggestion. because it has nice way of writing, but move later on application which i am not looking for.( application on pde is fine though)